# How to select particular element in react native from hundreds of the same kind like 'getElementById()' in javascript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a screen like the following:

[image: This is how the icons are placed in posts]

As you can see this is displaying posts from users. There are hundreds of posts. Currently, I am struggling with the like/unlike system. I have a API to send data and perform a like/unlike in the database. The problem is how can I update the like/unlike state here?

Suppose, there are 2 loves in a post. **Someone pressed love on it. API request sent to database and he/she successfully loved it. But as the screen was displaying 'unliked' situation(for example it was grey in color) how can I update that particular icon to 'liked' situation(for example it should be red in color now).**

So, I was wondering if there is any method to select a particular element from many of them in react native. I programmed the web version using javascript where I set unique id for every icon and used the 'getElementById()' method to update a particular one.

I am new to react native, so please forgive my problems or thinking. You can show me different way to achieve what am I wanting, if you think you have a better idea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try **not** to think in terms of grabbing the id of a HTML element. Each heart would be an individual component i.e a function or class therefore would be separate JavaScript object.

A good resource to help understand and think in terms of Component concepts on React official site [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

So each card may have

```
<Card>
   <Header>...with User avatar, name, posted time</Header>
   <Comment>foo bar....</Comment>
   <Heart /> // This render of heart will be a separate object to the next 
           // Render of heart on another card
</Card>
```

Essential then on the render of the "Heart" component, you could set it's state and then just change state on press.

```
//Using hooks
 const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);

// On mount call api if post is liked setIsLike(true)


function onPressOfHeart() {
    // any Api calls
    setIsLiked(!isLiked); // Update heart to be true
}

return (
    <View>
        <Image> source={isLiked ? colorPinkUrl : colorGreyUrl}  </Image>
    </View>
)
```

If you are not using hooks, from the parent class you can pass props true/false to the heart component

** EDITED TO REFLECT YOUR SNACK

[MySnack](https://snack.expo.io/@t-minus/moody-watermelon)

By passing the prop **isLiked** it will mean any state change on parent will be refreshed on child component. I have written a simplified version to show you how the components individually maintains there own reference to state.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { isLiked: true, id: 12843 },
        { isLiked: false, id: 1267 },
        { isLiked: true, id: 154523 },
        { isLiked: false, id: 1256453 },
        { isLiked: false, id: 123454 },
      ],
      isPress: false,
    };
  }

  heartOnPress = (id) => {
    // This  OnPress would trigger your api call to Add/REmove like from user ?
    // But for this example will directly manipulate state
    this.setState((state) => {
      const data = state.data.map((el) => {
        if(el.id === id) {
          el.isLiked = !el.isLiked;
        }
        return el;
      });
      const isPress = !state.isPress
      return { data, isPress };
    });
  };

  renderListItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>Press Me =></Text>
        <Heart isLiked={item.isLiked} id={item.id} onPress={this.heartOnPress} />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={this.renderListItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Heart.js

```
const Heart = ({ isLiked, onPress, id }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {isLiked ? (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(id)}>
          <Icon name="heart" size={30} color="red" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(id)}>
          <Icon name="heart" size={30} color="grey" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. here is my snack: https://snack.expo.io/@nothingtosay/privileged-toffee can i do like you said in my code?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your snack hope that helps

Comment: Ok added a snack and a working example @NothingtoSay. You can see how the component can be passed props including a function which is called on press only effecting the item pressed. Hope this helps !